# Error with query in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

Can't I use double condition in where clause in query. LIke I have used query..

```
 mysql_query("DELETE * FROM srelsg WHERE skey='".$childid."' AND sgkey='".$sgid."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

but its giving me syntax error. Might be I am using double variables in WHERE for delete query. Any other solution I can do it. Because combination of both variable make my tupple unique. else both field exist number of times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should not be a `*` between `DELETE` and `FROM`. Change this:

```
DELETE * FROM srelsg WHERE ...
```

To this:

```
DELETE FROM srelsg WHERE ...
```

See the [`DELETE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) in the MySQL manual.

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to Mark Byers - use `mysql_real_escape_string`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php